# Can one set the timeout in Retrofit2 on android without creating an okHttpClient?

Tags: android, networking, retrofit2

I'm currently building a `Retrofit` object as follows:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
  .build();
```

I don't need to pass it a client, i.e. no need to deal with the internals.

Now I would like to set a timeout, but all the examples I found involve creating an `okHttpClient` and assigning it to the `Retrofit` object.

Does it mean that okHttp is the de-facto client used by the system in all the situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that okHttp is the de-facto client used by the system in all the situations?

Yes. Retrofit uses OkHttp for its network I/O. For example, in [the Retrofit documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/#download), they mention in the section on R8/Proguard:

> You might also need rules for OkHttp and Okio which are dependencies of this library